# 3d mouse events : for z dimension

Tags: html, 3d, mouseevent

I'm soon to be purchasing a 3d mouse and it just clicked (pardon the pun), does javascript or html5 spec support a mouse move event for the z dimension. Or a similar alternative for 3d movements on a webpage?

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt it. HTML based webpages are pretty much assumed to be 2D.

Comment: I tend to agree, but I wonder with the inception of WebGL and the multitude of 3d libraries geared up to support rendering of 3d, if perhaps 3d input might also begin to be supported.